# Storage schema retention and aggregation

Tags: graphite

In Graphite storage schema retention is configured as:

"10s:1d,1m:30d"

And aggregation methods of min, max, sum, average.

**Question**: When viewing the charts/graphs where you see what retention and aggregation method Graphite is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphite's retentions and aggregation methods are not visible on graphs because it doesn't belong to graphs - it belongs to individual metrics, and the graph can contain many metrics.
You can run `whisper-info.py` a tool with metrics wsp-file - then you'll get which retention and aggregation it has. But usually, your wsp files have same retention / aggeregation which were described in configs.

Comment: I installed Graphite through the Ubuntu repositories, I don't see a whisper-info.py file under /var/lib/graphite/whisper, how do I get similar info with Ubuntu distros ?

Comment: It's not under /var/lib/graphite/whisper, it's a part of python-whisper package, should be in /usr/bin, can be named `whisper-info`, w/o .py extension

Comment: Thanks, I get output like this, is the retention here specified in seconds?  Also any idea what happens if you change the retention policy for a metric does it update it right away, what happens in that case?

maxRetention: 86400
xFilesFactor: 0.5
aggregationMethod: average
fileSize: 3220

Archive 0
retention: 600
secondsPerPoint: 10
points: 60
size: 720
offset: 52

Archive 1
retention: 3600
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 60
size: 720
offset: 772

Archive 2
retention: 86400
secondsPerPoint: 600
points: 144
size: 1728
offset: 1492

Comment: Yes, time is in seconds. Unfortunately, retentions and aggregations are encoded in wsp file, so, you need or delete old file and let Graphite recreate it with new parameters (and loose historical data, obviously) - or use whisper-resize to change it. Please check https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper#whisper-resizepy

Comment: ahh ok, that make sense.  Ok, last question as I'm still confused on the graph.  If there is a retention policy like 1m:30d, 1h:1y, with the graphs if I change graph date range to past 3 hours which one will it use the 1m or 1h ?  And in general will that have any impact on the results ?

Comment: If you have such retention policy then you can pick any range up to 30 days - you'll get non-aggregated data from archive 0. If you will ask data for more than 30 days (but less then 1y) - you will get aggregated data from Archive 1 (1 point per hour, which was aggregated from corresponding 60 points from Archive 0, using your aggregation function  - avg in your case)

Comment: And if you ask data for more that 1 year - you'll get nothing (for aggregation scheme above ofc)

Comment: Thanks for the help!